# Is it possible to detect data changes as well ? I mean DML changes

Tags: liquibase

Liquibase main purpose is for detecting DDL (schema) changes.
Can it be used to deploy DML (data) changes as well ?
I mean is it possible to write changesets for doing inserts with data?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible with liquibase.

Just use [`<update>`](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/update.html) tag for data update.

Or use [`<sql>`](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html) tag for data insert or for whatever SQL queries you actually want.

Comment: Agreed - one thing to be aware of though is that this should mainly be used for things like configuration data, semi-constant stuff, and test data. It would not be appropriate to use for production data, large volumes of data, etc. Also be aware that once you have created a changeset, it cannot be changed after it has been deployed to a database, so to add more rows to a table you would need to write an additional changeset.